# AngularJS - stop ng-click expression evaluation after $event.stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-ng-click

I'm struggling stoping ng-click from evaluating the rest of expression after event cancelation was called.

I've made the following [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzXwbO5kpZWmkSiBg88Z?p=preview).

If you click on "Click me" text, you'll see that the value is changing, although the clickMe function is calling all known methods (by me, at least) to stop the event.

Markup:

```
 <body ng-controller="Home" ng-init="model = { value: false }">
    <div ng-click="clickMe($event); model.value = true;">Click me!!</div>
    {{ model.value }}
  </body>
```

App:

```
APP.controller('Home', function($scope){
  $scope.clickMe = function($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})
```

I know that I can pass arguments to clickMe function and if "isOK" is false, then update what I need, but for many reasons bound to my application, I try not to do that.

#### Update

In my app I had something like this on ng-click

```
model.PS.title = value; model.PS.desc = value2; model.PS.isSce = value3
```

I was blind and I couldn't see that I can make it a lot simpler like this:

```
model.PS = { title: value, desc: value2, isSce: value3 }
```

... and in this case i can use the shorthand expression for if statement like @Emmanuel mentioned.

I was thinking that ngClick evaluates the expressions inside it like a function block, so if it meets a `return false` (or something similar) it stops there.

Comment: `model.value = true;` is a different expression. That has nothing to do with the `clickMe` function call that comes before it. If you don't want to change the value, then don't change it.

Comment: oh... so ng-click doesn't take all those expressions like a unit? I was thinking that if I throw somewhere inside ng-click a canceling event, then everything will stop at that specific point.

Comment: No, it's just a normal javascript expression. That's two lines of code like any other lines of code separated by a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
<body ng-controller="Home" ng-init="model = { value: false }">
    <div ng-click="model.value = clickMe($event) ? true : model.value;">Click me!!</div>
    {{ model.value }}
</body>
```

Leave App as is

```
APP.controller('Home', function($scope){
  $scope.clickMe = function($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})
```

Comment: 1st solution would've been great if I had just one value to update, but if there are more like `mode.value = true; model.value2 = false;` then the rest of expressions will get evaluated.
2nd one doesn't work, afaik, because you cannot put if condition inside ng-click.

Comment: i've come to this simple solution in the end. see my updated post above for explanations. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could evaluate your expression after you have run your click handler with `$scope.$eval`.

You can pass your expression that you want to run after the click is valid to your click handler and evaluate the expression depending on your `isOK` variable.

I've extended the demo a bit to show the functionality of `$eval`.

Please find the updated plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Afm49EnQtHGg9pvfGqMc?p=preview).

**HTML**

```
 <body ng-controller="Home" ng-init="model = { value: false }; model2 = {value:true}">
     <div ng-click="clickMe($event, 'model.value = true; model2.value = false;');">Click me!!</div>
     {{ model.value }}

     {{ model2.value }}
     <br/>
     check to enable click me!
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model='isOK'/>
 </body>
```

**JS**

```
var APP = angular.module('myApp', []);

APP.controller('Home', function($scope){
       //var isOk = true;
        $scope.isOK = false;

        $scope.clickMe = function($event, args){

        if($scope.isOK){
            console.log(args);
            $scope.$eval(args);
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('isOk false:', args);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this works, but not the way I want to. thanks though!